# getting permission denied while creating SSH

Tags: ssh

```
[sneha@localhost ~]$  ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "sneha.22.7@gmail.com"

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/sneha/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/sneha/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/sneha/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
c8:50:db:0d:eb:cc:23:b3:8a:90:6c:32:80:e8:e2:cc sneha.22.7@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:

+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|      . .        |
|     . o +       |
|    . . o .      |
|o    o =         |
|+     = S        |
|+.     + .       |
|*+    .          |
|Bo . .           |
| E. .            |
+-----------------+

[sneha@localhost ~]$ /home/sneha/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
bash: /home/sneha/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
```

can anyone help? i'm pretty sure i am doing everything required

Answer (score 1):

`id_rsa.pub` is not an executable file, it's a public key. Trying to run a regular file will give you a permission denied error. What are you trying to do? Normally you would append that file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be the SELINUX is set to enabled. This SELINUX is an extra layer of security provided by linux. In such a case we won’t be able to create the private and public key. We have permission provided to users. But not at Applications level.

To do this go to /etc/selinux/config and set SELINUX=disable